# Sending email issue with other server

Tags: php, phpmailer

**I am facing some problem with email sending script that i am exploring bellow.**

```
 try 
     {
       $mail->Host       = "mail.xyz.com"; // SMTP server
      $mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
      $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
      $mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
      $mail->Username   = "no-reply@xyz.com"; // SMTP account username
      $mail->Password   = "mypassword";        // SMTP account password*/
      $mail->SetFrom($from, $fromName);
      $mail->AddAddress($to, $toName);
      $mail->Subject = $subject;
      $mail->AddReplyTo('no-reply@xyz.com', 'xyz title');         
      $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible        email viewer!'; // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
      $mail->MsgHTML($body);
      $mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
      $success = $mail->Send();
    } 
    catch (phpmailerException $e)
    {
      echo $e->errorMessage(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
      echo $e->getMessage(); 
    }
    return $success;
```

**I am using this code with PHPMailer to send email it's working fine to me for

- xyz@gmail.com
- xyz@yahoo.com
- xyz@rediff.com

  but when i am sending mail to hotmail like xyz@hotmail.com or xyz@live.com then it       goes    to junk folder. What should be issue? Also when i am trying to send email at my    company server like kajal@xyztechnologies.com then got following error:**

  ---------------------------- Original Message ----------------------------
    Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
    From:    "Mail Delivery System" 
    Date:    Mon, October 7, 2013 6:23 pm
    To:      no-reply@xyz.com

  ---

  This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.

  A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
     recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

  ```
  kajal@xyztechnologies.com
  SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<no-reply@xyz.com> SIZE=1872:
  host xyztechnologies.com [173.37.185.97]:
  550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)
  ```

  ------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------

  Return-path: 
     Received: from localhost ([127.0.0.1]:47913 helo=www.xyz.com)
  by rack with esmtpa (Exim 4.80.1)
  (envelope-from )
  id 1VT8up-0007gh-UD
  for kajal@xyztechnologies.com; Mon, 07 Oct 2013 18:23:55 +0700
      Received: from 122.177.170.230 ([122.177.170.230]) (proxying for 10.1.1.12)
      (SquirrelMail authenticated user no-reply@xyz.com)
      by www.xyz.com with HTTP;
      Mon, 7 Oct 2013 18:23:55 +0700
      Message-ID: <55932ee6e029216dc42c4ba45cb93b56.squirrel@www.xyz.com>
      Date: Mon, 7 Oct 2013 18:23:55 +0700
      Subject: Test From webmail
       From: no-reply@xyz.com
      To: kajal@xyztechnologies.com
      User-Agent: SquirrelMail/1.4.22
      MIME-Version: 1.0
      Content-Type: text/plain;charset=iso-8859-1
      Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
      X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
      Importance: Normal

  ```
  TEsst2
  ```

  What should be issue? I am unable to find any solution. Please help me.
  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally this has everything to do with the mail server and protocol you are using...

Mail sent through php using sendmail does not have to be verified and can be sent anonymously... this is probably a reason why your email's are ending up caught in spam folders...

I recommend using an authenticated smtp server there verifies the sender's identity (that also needs to match the from header), you will have a much better chance getting to the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the FROM email, and it needs to be from the domain which it is sent, otherwise many host providers will flag it as spam.

This will work, because it identifies the email as having been sent from your  domain.
$headers[] = 'From: Someone Maybe You ';

This will not work, it will be flagged as spam.
$headers[] = 'From: Someone Maybe You ';